# Reference book for practice problems on Inference

Tags: references, inference, consistency, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

I was wondering if there is any book which has loads of problems on statistical inference.

Desired topics are

- Unbiasedness
- Consistency
- Sufficiency
- Completeness
- Rao Blackwell Theorem
- etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend three books :

- [Statistical Inference 2nd Edition by Casella and Berger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126) Chapter 6 and Chapter 7 .
- [Introduction to the Theory of Statistics by Mood](https://www.amazon.de/Introduction-Theory-Statistics-Alexander-Mood/dp/0070854653) Chapter VII
- My favorite book [Mathematical Statistics for Economics and Business by Mittelhammer](https://www.amazon.de/Mathematical-Statistics-Economics-Business-Mittelhammer/dp/1461450217/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) Chapter 7 and Chapter 8